# How to determine return type based on optional parameter's type

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, optional-parameters

I have the following function:

```
export function safeParseInt<T>(value: any, invalid: T = undefined as T): number | T {
  if ((value ?? "") === "") return invalid;
  const parsed = parseInt(String(value));
  if (isNaN(parsed)) return invalid;
  return value ? parsed : 0;
}
```

[See this in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwM4CGCwACgVHsAJIowA8AKgHwAUAbgQDZLABccBFAE8ANHEwoOnTABN+DOAF44qGcAQTgMgXjgMAlPxRIAtgCNgUOAB89cAN4AoOOIRwW7LjzgB+H3AAiAP0lRWUgkKhgGCQoXAkpWQBuZzg0HDx4MHJKbWVsimpaFgBlGCgJAHNPbmB9fRSXTDcWTDwAOQJ2lgLc+rgomLjxSS5k1MHY3F6tFIBfR0dkdCwcOBhgTJqeflQAaxQIAHcUEKcXdJRMgaV8IlIcophtusa0jPgQI1MLK1sg26EYhkQo0Z5SHgNVKXa5Cb7mSw2QIBQH3EGUMEvMQRN4w+AAL3hvyRAOUQIeoOKEOAYlU6k0MgacEcCyAA)

As you can see it takes two parameters and returns either the first parameter converted into an integer or the second one if it is unable. The second one is optional and defaults to undefined.

I am having difficulty typing this. If I use the version above:

```
function test(value: unknown) {
  const r = safeParseInt(value);
  const x: number | "" = safeParseInt(value);
  const y: number | "" = safeParseInt(value, "");
  const z: number | "" = safeParseInt(value, undefined); 
}
```

I expected an error on `x` and `z`, but there is only one on `z`. When I hover over `r` I can see that the return type is `unknown`.

Something about the default value is messing up the inference. I've tried returning `typeof invalid`, removing type hints altogether, making T extend undefined or making it extend unknown. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use overloads.

```
export function safeParseInt(value: any): number | undefined
export function safeParseInt<T>(value: any, invalid: T): number | T
export function safeParseInt<T>(value: any, invalid: T = undefined as T): number | T {
  if ((value ?? "") === "") return invalid;
  const parsed = parseInt(String(value));
  if (isNaN(parsed)) return invalid;
  return parsed;
}
```

This will explicitly set the return type of `safeParseInt` to `number | undefined` if `invalid` is not passed to the function.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwM4CGCwACgVHsAJIowAUAbgQDZLABccBKAngJScUSALYAjYFDgAfOKgAmwBJhTA5AKFCRYiVBmy5CxMhWq0APABUAfIxZtO3HgBo4yps0xzOFgXCFiJaTgLDXBoeGR0LBx8IlJyShoYSxt3ey5eFzcWT284AF5ZFAUlFTkuPGDff3FJGQs4AG81OFcEODpbVmA4AH5euAAiQb4C-MLh0ahgGCQoXGyPOQBuFrg0HDx4MATVArgdkyS6AGUYKGUAcy62Pj5V1sx2ukw8ADkCN7pDyjk7uGms3mrhQ7k8DwBMzmuB+qlWAF81GpInoYjBgFsbhwigBrFAQADuKFGzVaGxQWwB+0M8SOtCx9zW5MpIEEIlqQWG1LixkS9LSwEZZM28B4bICdSGg25Rl2xwFLkmEOZ8AAXuKOTIuYUabzTPQFUUSspVPc4GpEUA)

Answer (score 1):

With the way the function is currently declared it returns an `unknown` result if no `invalid` argument is provided. I've correctly the typing slightly [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwM4CGCwACgVHsAJIowA8AKgLyoAmwCmKwrAfABQA3AgBskwAFxxUAaxQQA7igA0cLsJGZWAfgkMAlFJRIAtgCNgUOAB84DOAG8AUHDUI4-IaPFxt2uABEAfpwTGGBwXBQwDBIULjqolpwBHh2ANwucGg4ePBg5JSsoXAFFNS0-ADKMFBcAOZeYsD6+pmumO78mHgAcgS9-GVFrVExcQkoGsmpGVnRsfGlhTyZAL5Om8joWDhwMACeYMAA4kjkrPzk9UamFla2QSHOrgsTKVD1ThtO2xjYuBgwDyTXEUlk8iUzyyORQeSiJUIxDI5RoMFBLXacAA9NjXK4AHraGG5eAgW7mSw2OBmCAQETAAi4Jj4IikFZojFtLK4-FwIkkuHwA6ItkoyicjTiVRPLG8-EC1yw+EAL1FyI5lSlwFUbA4XB4bTgPLxCuJWUOxzOF34UH0FqOp3OUEuIHtrktTptB3d+0d1pd-BV9o2QA)

Of course, this still doesn't pass the test you've written (more below on why). But this functions is typed correctly. If you try to use the outputs in a function that doesn't accept the same signature, the compiler will warn you (added this in the playground link as well)

For why this works... When you declare a type with the variable, like `const var: <type> = ...`, typescript will use what you've given to infer any generic types.

So when you call the function without the `invalid` argument, typescript uses your type declaration to "guess" that the fallback argument must be of type `""`. But when you explicitly pass the argument, it uses the actual arguments type to infer the generic.

This inference doesn't happen when you use the arguments. Which is why the typescript throws an error when I try passing it to a function.